# reading files from a directory using perl script

Tags: perl, file-read

I have a directory with multiple files. The files are named as follows A11111, A22222, A33333, B11111, B22222, B33333 and so on. I want to read these files, perform certain formatting options on the content and write it to the output file. But for all files beginning with A, I want just one output file, for all files beginning with B, I want one output file and so on. Is it possible to do this with perl script?

Comment: It is possible. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [Show your progress and code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) Explain where you are stuck without the help of others.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible or if someone here will provide the code to do it? It is certainly possible

Comment: Anything is possible with Perl!

Answer (score 1):

The following example should be a good start for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '.';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @files = sort grep { ! -d } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

$dir =~ s/\/$//;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  next if $file !~ /^[A-Z](\d)\1{4}$/;

  my $output = substr($file, 0, 1);
  open(my $ih, '<',  "$dir/$file")   or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";
  open(my $oh, '>>', "$dir/$output") or die "Could not open file '$output' $!";

  $_ = <$ih>;
  # perform certain formating with $_ here
  print $oh $_;

  close($ih);
  close($oh);
}
```

---

At line `next if $file !~ /^[A-Z](\d)\1{4}$/;` it skips all filenames that are not in required format, which is first character is capital letter, second is number and another 4 characters are same as the first number.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on linux use `cat file1 file2 ... > bigfile

otherwise here is a small script to help you on the way

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# get the directory from the commandline
# and clean ending /
my $dirname = $ARGV[0];
$dirname =~ s/\/$//;

# get a list of all files in directory; ignore all files beginning with a .
opendir(my $dh, $dirname) || die "can't opendir $dirname: $!";
my @files = grep { /^[^\.]/ && -f "$dirname/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;

# loop through the files and write all beginning with 
# A to file A, B to file B, etc. extent the regex to fit your needs 
foreach my $file (@files) {
    if ($file =~ /([AB])\d+/) {
        open(IN,  "< $dirname/$file") or die "cant open $dirname/$file for reading";
        open(OUT, ">> $dirname/$1") or die "cant open $dirname/$1 for appending";
        print OUT <IN>;
        close(OUT);
        close(IN); 
    } else {
        print "$file didn't match\n";
    }
}
```